# java 11 NoSuchMethodError javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement.addAttribute

Tags: java, xml, soap, java-11

I got this runtime error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement.addAttribute(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/xml/soap/SOAPElement;
```

I have this lines in my build.gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api
compile group: 'javax.xml.soap', name: 'javax.xml.soap-api', version: '1.4.0'

compile group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-ri', version: '2.3.2', ext: 'pom'
```

but project still throw this error. and additional question: how it compiled if  I have wrong dependencies :)